# Many to One relationship sub pages / page on same table?

Tags: entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship, doctrine-orm

Using ZF and Doctrine. I have a table 'pages'. I want to have it so that some pages can have sub pages associated with it. The sub pages should also have a reference to their (one and only) parent page.

I know I could split this between 2 entities (page / subpage), but I know it's possible with one entity, but can't figure out how to make the relationship work.

The way I invision it, is a second table would be the mapping table (page_id, parent_page_id).

I'm using annotation reference in my entities and here is what i'm doing so far, any help would be appreciated, in a late night crunch.

```
    /**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Page", mappedBy="parentPage")
 */
private $subPages;


/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="subPages")
 */
private $parentPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this question is here, in the Doctrine documentation, under *One-To-Many, Self-referencing*:

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing

Here is an example:

```
class Pages{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * one page have several referred pages
     * @var Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Pages", mappedBy="parentPage")
     */
    private $subPages;

    /**
     * many referred pages have one referral page
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pages", inversedBy="subPages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_page", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $parentPage;
    private $referredBy;



    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->subPages = new Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```